# How to filter with Contains a vlaue object type in DDD repository?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, contains, iqueryable, value-objects

I developed a project with the DDD method to manage holidays. I have 2 value objects with the names of HolidayTitle and HolidayDate.
Now I want to filter with Contains in the Query Repository but I can't.

My code in the repository is as follows:

```
public async Task<ListResponse<IList<GetHolidaysByDatesDto>>> GetHolidays(GetHolidaysQuery param)
        {
            var query = _repository.AsQueryable();

            if (param.Date.HasValue)
                query = query.Where(x => x.Date == param.Date);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.Title))
                query = query.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(param.Title));

            var pagingData = await query.GetPagingData(param);

            query = query.SetPaging(param);
            var holidays = await query.ToListAsync();

            var mappedResult = _mapper.Map<IList<GetHolidaysByDatesDto>>(holidays);

            var finalResult = new ListResponse<IList<GetHolidaysByDatesDto>>()
            {
                PageCount = pagingData.PageCount,
                PageNumber = pagingData.PageNumber,
                RowCount = pagingData.RowCount,
                Result = mappedResult
            };

            return finalResult;
        }
```

And the codes of the HolidayTitle are as follows

```
public class HolidayTitle : BaseValueObject<HolidayTitle>
    {
        public static readonly int minLength = 5;
        public static readonly int maxLength = 300;

        public string Value { get; private set; }

        private HolidayTitle(string value)
        {
            if (value is null)
                throw new NullOrEmptyArgumentException(HolidayErrors.HolidayTitleIsNull);

            value = value.Trim();

            if (value == string.Empty)
                throw new NullOrEmptyArgumentException(HolidayErrors.HolidayTitleIsEmpty);

            if (value.Length > maxLength || value.Length < minLength)
                throw new RangeLengthArgumentException(HolidayErrors.HolidayTitleLengthIsNotInRangeLength, minLength.ToString(), maxLength.ToString());

            Value = value;
        }

        public bool Contains(string str)
        {
            return Value.Contains(str);
        }

        public override bool IsEqual(HolidayTitle otherObject)
        {
            return Value == otherObject.Value;
        }

        public override int ObjectGetHashCode()
        {
            return Value.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static implicit operator string(HolidayTitle value)
        {
            return value.Value;
        }

        public static HolidayTitle GetInstance(string value)
        {
            return new(value);
        }
    }
```

I get this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Holiday>()
.Where(h => !(h.IsDeleted))
.Where(h => h.Title.Contains(__param_Title_0))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'Core.Domain.Holidays.ValueObjects.HolidayTitle.Contains' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

Comment: try `query.AsEnumerable().Where......`?

Comment: Shall I add my comment as answer?

Comment: I have added the answer, please accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF is not able to translate this to a query. One way you can load the whole data into the memory and than filter it.

You have to use the below, as the `query` is `IQueryable`:

```
query.AsEnumerable()
     .Where......
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is good enough. It's hard to see how this solves OP's problem. Can you explain why this works? It seems to me that the actual problem is that EF Core cannot translate the function Contains from class HolidayTitle into valid SQL. If your solution works, my guess is that it is just working around the problem by loading the whole table into memory and doing the filtering there, which is not a valid solution for most realistic scenarios.

Comment: @FrancescCastells thank you for reviewing. I have added the info in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write

```cs
     query = query.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(param.Title));
```

because EF does not know your `HolidayTitle.Contains` method.

On the other hand, EF knows how to translate the method `string.Contains`:

```cs
     query = query.Where(x => x.Title.Value.Contains(param.Title));
```

Comment: I agree with the first part of your statement, but I do not agree with the code you wrote. Because the "Value" is not available in this section.

Comment: Sorry, try `x.Title.Value.Contains(param.Title)` (I fix it)

Comment: I get the same error again.